# Function resets variable after being used

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to remake a very basic battle in Pokémon. Right now yourhp = 20 and enemyhp = 20 which is suppose to be how much health the yours and the enemies Pokémon have. Currently trying to recreate the function (enemytackle) so that I am able to use the same function for both the user using tackle and the enemy using tackle. As of now enemytackle will work fine but yourhp will reset to 20 then take in account of the damage. (Example is using tackle the first time may do 3 damage going from 20 to 17, but using it the second time will reset yourhp back to 20) The major difference I see is the use of 'global' but in order to use global yourhp and global enemyhp (for me at least) it seems like I would have to create another function just to use the two separately when everything else would be the same.

```
import random

starter = ['Charmander', 'Bulbasaur', 'Squirtle']
options = ['Attack', 'Pokeball', 'Items', 'Run']
attacks = ['Tackle', 'Tail-Whip']
choice = None
name = None
pokemonchoice = None
starterchoice = None
rivalchoice = None

enemyhp = 20
yourhp = 20
turns = 1
lowereddefense1 = 0
lowereddefense2 = 0

while choice != 'yes':
    print('Please enter a number')
    starterchoice = input('> ')
    if starterchoice.isnumeric():
        if starterchoice == '1' or starterchoice == '2' or starterchoice == '3':
            starterchoice = int(starterchoice)
            pokemonchoice = starter[starterchoice - 1]
            print(f'Are you sure you want to choose {pokemonchoice}')
            choice = input('> ').casefold()


if starterchoice == 1:
    rivalchoice = starter[2]
elif starterchoice == 2:
    rivalchoice = starter[0]
elif starterchoice == 3:
    rivalchoice = starter[1]


def yourtackle(totaldamge, lowereddefense, pokemon1, pokemon2, pokemonhp):
    '''
    totaldamage: The amount of damage the pokemon will take, damage is calculated based off of a random number +
    the additional with lowered defense
    lowerredefense: The additional damage the pokemon will take with totaldamage, can go up to +4, defualts at 0
    '''
    global enemyhp
    print(f'{pokemon1} used Tackle!')
    totaldamge = totaldamge + lowereddefense
    pokemonhp -= totaldamge
    print(f'You did {totaldamge} damage! {pokemon2} has {pokemonhp}hp left!')
    print('*' * 80)


def enemytackle(totaldamage, lowereddefense):
    '''
    totaldamage: The amount of damage the pokemon will take, damage is calculated based off of a random number +
    the additional with lowered defense
    lowerredefense: The additional damage the pokemon will take with totaldamage, can go up to +4, defualts at 0
    '''
    global yourhp
    print(f'{rivalchoice} used Tackle!')
    totaldamage = totaldamage + lowereddefense
    yourhp -= totaldamage
    print(f'Gary did {totaldamage} damage! {pokemonchoice} has {yourhp}hp left!')
    print('*' * 80)


while enemyhp > 0 and yourhp > 0:
    if turns % 2 == 0:   # Enemies move
        enemysturn = random.randint(1, 2)
        if enemysturn == 1:
            damage = random.randint(1, 4)
            enemytackle(damage, lowereddefense2)
            turns += 1
        elif enemysturn == 2:
            print('*' * 80)
            print(f'{rivalchoice} used Tail-Whip!')
            turns += 1
            if lowereddefense2 == 4:
                print(f"{pokemonchoice} defense cannot be lowered more!")
                print('*' * 80)
            else:
                print(f'{pokemonchoice} defense was decreased!')
                print('*' * 80)
                lowereddefense2 += 1
    else:    # Your move
        print('What do you choose')
        for number, option in enumerate(options):
            print(f'{number + 1}. {option}')
        battle = input('> ')
        if battle == '1':
            for attacknum, attack in enumerate(attacks):
                print(attacknum + 1, attack)
            move = input('> ')
            if move == '1':
                damage = random.randint(1, 4)
                yourtackle(damage, lowereddefense1, starterchoice, rivalchoice, enemyhp)
                turns += 1
            elif move == '2':
                print(f'{pokemonchoice} used Tail-Whip!')
                turns += 1
                if lowereddefense1 == 4:
                    print(f"{rivalchoice} defense cannot be lowered more!")
                else:
                    print(f'{rivalchoice} defense was decreased!')
                    lowereddefense1 += 1
        elif battle == '2':
            print("You cannot use pokeballs on other trainer's pokemon!")
        elif battle == '3':
            print("You currently have no items!")
        elif battle == '4':
            print("You may not run from trainer battles")

if yourhp > enemyhp:
    print('You Win!')
else:
    print('You lose')
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would cause `yourhp` to be reset to 20, unless you are running the *entire* script multiple times in the same interpreter.

Comment: Don't use a global, do something like `enemyhp = tackle(enemyhp, ...)` pass in the current hp and return the new hp, then you won't need two separate functions.

Comment: @TypicalTy I have fixed a few bugs in your code below. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Python does not pass by reference. This means when you modify `pokemonhp` (which is an immutable integer) inside a function the change does not modify the value of `pokemonhp` that was passed as an argument to that function. Here is an example of how you can change your code to correctly modify the value you want to.

Looks like a fun game! Good luck with the rest of it.

Edit: you had a second bug where you were using `starterchoice` instead of `pokemonchoice` which I also fix here.

```
import random

starter = ['Charmander', 'Bulbasaur', 'Squirtle']
options = ['Attack', 'Pokeball', 'Items', 'Run']
attacks = ['Tackle', 'Tail-Whip']
choice = None
name = None
pokemonchoice = None
starterchoice = None
rivalchoice = None

enemyhp = 20
yourhp = 20
turns = 1
lowereddefense1 = 0
lowereddefense2 = 0

while choice != 'yes':
    print('Please enter a number')
    starterchoice = input('> ')
    if starterchoice.isnumeric():
        if starterchoice == '1' or starterchoice == '2' or starterchoice == '3':
            starterchoice = int(starterchoice)
            pokemonchoice = starter[starterchoice - 1]
            print(f'Are you sure you want to choose {pokemonchoice}')
            choice = input('> ').casefold()


if starterchoice == 1:
    rivalchoice = starter[2]
elif starterchoice == 2:
    rivalchoice = starter[0]
elif starterchoice == 3:
    rivalchoice = starter[1]


def tackle(totaldamage, lowereddefense, pokemon1, pokemon2, pokemonhp, user):
    '''
    totaldamage: The amount of damage the pokemon will take, damage is calculated based off of a random number +
    the additional with lowered defense
    lowerredefense: The additional damage the pokemon will take with totaldamage, can go up to +4, defualts at 0
    '''

    print(f'{pokemon1} used Tackle!')
    totaldamage = totaldamage + lowereddefense
    print(f'{user} did {totaldamage} damage! {pokemon2} has {pokemonhp - totaldamage}hp left!')
    print('*' * 80)
    return totaldamage


# def enemytackle(totaldamage, lowereddefense):
#     '''
#     totaldamage: The amount of damage the pokemon will take, damage is calculated based off of a random number +
#     the additional with lowered defense
#     lowerredefense: The additional damage the pokemon will take with totaldamage, can go up to +4, defualts at 0
#     '''
#     global yourhp
#     print(f'{rivalchoice} used Tackle!')
#     totaldamage = totaldamage + lowereddefense
#     print(f'Gary did {totaldamage} damage! {pokemonchoice} has {yourhp - totaldamage}hp left!')
#     print('*' * 80)
#     return totaldamage


while enemyhp > 0 and yourhp > 0:
    if turns % 2 == 0:   # Enemies move
        enemysturn = random.randint(1, 2)
        if enemysturn == 1:
            damage = random.randint(1, 4)
            yourhp -= tackle(damage, lowereddefense2, rivalchoice, pokemonchoice, yourhp, "Gary")
            turns += 1
        elif enemysturn == 2:
            print('*' * 80)
            print(f'{rivalchoice} used Tail-Whip!')
            turns += 1
            if lowereddefense2 == 4:
                print(f"{pokemonchoice} defense cannot be lowered more!")
                print('*' * 80)
            else:
                print(f'{pokemonchoice} defense was decreased!')
                print('*' * 80)
                lowereddefense2 += 1
    else:    # Your move
        print('What do you choose')
        for number, option in enumerate(options):
            print(f'{number + 1}. {option}')
        battle = input('> ')
        if battle == '1':
            for attacknum, attack in enumerate(attacks):
                print(attacknum + 1, attack)
            move = input('> ')
            if move == '1':
                damage = random.randint(1, 4)
                enemyhp -= tackle(damage, lowereddefense1, pokemonchoice, rivalchoice, enemyhp, "You")
                turns += 1
            elif move == '2':
                print(f'{pokemonchoice} used Tail-Whip!')
                turns += 1
                if lowereddefense1 == 4:
                    print(f"{rivalchoice} defense cannot be lowered more!")
                else:
                    print(f'{rivalchoice} defense was decreased!')
                    lowereddefense1 += 1
        elif battle == '2':
            print("You cannot use pokeballs on other trainer's pokemon!")
        elif battle == '3':
            print("You currently have no items!")
        elif battle == '4':
            print("You may not run from trainer battles")

if yourhp > enemyhp:
    print('You Win!')
else:
    print('You lose')
```

Example output:

```
Please enter a number
> 1
Are you sure you want to choose Charmander
> yes
What do you choose
1. Attack
2. Pokeball
3. Items
4. Run
> 1
1 Tackle
2 Tail-Whip
> 1
Charmander used Tackle!
You did 1 damage! Squirtle has 19hp left!
********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************
Squirtle used Tail-Whip!
Charmander defense was decreased!
********************************************************************************
What do you choose
1. Attack
2. Pokeball
3. Items
4. Run
> 1
1 Tackle
2 Tail-Whip
> 1
Charmander used Tackle!
You did 3 damage! Squirtle has 16hp left!
********************************************************************************
Squirtle 1
Squirtle used Tackle!
Gary did 3 damage! Charmander has 17hp left!
********************************************************************************
What do you choose
1. Attack
2. Pokeball
3. Items
4. Run
> 1
1 Tackle
2 Tail-Whip
> 1
Charmander used Tackle!
You did 3 damage! Squirtle has 13hp left!
********************************************************************************
Squirtle 1
Squirtle used Tackle!
Gary did 4 damage! Charmander has 13hp left!
********************************************************************************
What do you choose
1. Attack
2. Pokeball
3. Items
4. Run
>
```

Comment: This is close. The problem is that I think the OP wants to replace enemytackle with yourtackle - so they only use 1 function... `yourtackle` still uses `global enemyhp`, which is a problem.

Comment: @Shmack good call, I condensed both tackle functions into one